# How to execute Google Cloud Run service every N minutes?

Tags: cron, google-cloud-run

I have a service in Goole Run Cloud. I run make it do work by sending HTTP request to the special url.

But I want to run that code very N minutes. So I'm searching the proper way to do it.

I need something like Cloud Cron that I can configure to make a special request every N minutes.

Comment: Something like this: https://cloud.google.com/scheduler ? If that's what you mean I'm happy to make that the answer.

Comment: @GabeWeiss thank you, yes this is the service I was looking for.

Comment: sweeeeeeet. :) Made it the answer for others to find easily.

Comment: @GabeWeiss haha =) Thank you again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloud Scheduler:  https://cloud.google.com/scheduler is the service you're looking for. It'll let you schedule events on a timer like you're looking to do.